# How to select a table element and run javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table and want to run js on click event of a button in the row (populated by datatables) i used the code from datatables website but seems not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#expvisa').on('click','button',function() {
         var msData = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
         alert( msData[0] +" salary is: "+ msData[4]);
     });
 });
```

```html
<table id="expvisa" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>EMP Id</th>
      <th>VISA OFFICE</th>
      <th>EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
      <th>QATAR ID</th>
      <th>ID MONTH</th>
      <th>Process </th>                
    </tr>
  </thead>            
</table>
```

This is the script creating the table.

```js
        function bringvisa_exp(){ 
  
   $.ajax({    
    url:"report_visaexp.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{comp_n:$('#comp_n').val(),visam_f:$('#visam_f').val()},
    async: false,
    success: function(dataX){ 
     obj = JSON.parse(dataX);
     $('#expvisa').DataTable({
     data: obj,
     "columnDefs":  [ {
     "targets": -1,
     "data": null,
     "defaultContent": "<button>Apply</button>"
         } ]
     } );    
    }        
   }); 
  }
```

[image]

Comment: where does the table and .row come from? and which data should be displayed, please add some more information.

Comment: @DavidBucka i have added details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this script inside `ajax call success function` block. Because your `click event` is bind before `DOM` is ready.

```
 $('#expvisa tbody').on('click','button',function() {
     var msData = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
     alert( msData[0] +" salary is: "+ msData[4]);
 });
```

Update your `bringvisa_exp()` function with following:

```
function bringvisa_exp(){       
        $.ajax({                
            url:"report_visaexp.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{comp_n:$('#comp_n').val(),visam_f:$('#visam_f').val()},
            async: false,
            success: function(dataX){   
                obj = JSON.parse(dataX);
                $('#expvisa').DataTable({
                  data: obj,
                  "columnDefs": [ {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button>Apply</button>"
                   } ]
                } );
                $('#expvisa').on('click','button',function() {
                  var msData = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
                  alert( msData[0] +" salary is: "+ msData[4]);
                });
            }                               
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: that was really helpful. Still msData dont get the values of table rows data.

Comment: where is your `table` variable and what this contains?

Comment: The table basic structure is done by HTML code and it is manipulated or populated via function of jquery datatables. Added a screen shot to the original question.

Comment: Try this `var msData = table.row($(this).parent('tr')).data();`

Comment: @Jithendra, I fixed like declaring  var table = $('#expvisa').DataTable(); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I changed `$('#expvisa' tbody)` to  `$('#expvisa tbody')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#expvisa tbody').on('click','button',function() {
  var msData = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
  alert( msData[0] +" salary is: "+ msData[4]);
    });
});
```

Comment: it is already changed, but no luck. Is that the proper method to listen to a button click event that lies in the table ? like i did ?

Comment: it was to be included in the ajax success block. ie not to put that function in document ready block.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jithendra , I could fix this like and a minor edit to have the table variable also. I thought 'table' is a js/jq identifiable component. But it was not. So added `var table = $('#expvisa').DataTable();`

```js
function bringvisa_exp(){       
        $.ajax({                
            url:"report_visaexp.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{comp_n:$('#comp_n').val(),visam_f:$('#visam_f').val()},
            async: false,
            success: function(dataX){   
                obj = JSON.parse(dataX);
                $('#expvisa').DataTable({
                  data: obj,
                  "columnDefs": [ {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button>Apply</button>"
                   } ]
                } );
                $('#expvisa').on('click','button',function() {
                  var table = $('#expvisa').DataTable();
                  var msData = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
                  alert( msData[0] +" salary is: "+ msData[4]);
                });
            }                               
        }); 
    }
```